# Read resource information from an assembly at runtime

Tags: c#

```cs
var asm = Assembly.GetEntryAssembly();
this.Image = Properties.Resources.ResourceManager
                                .GetString(logicalOptions.GetType().Name);
```

Is there a way to retrieve the `ResourceManager` for an assembly which is dynamically discovered?

I would like to access the `ResourceManager` of the `asm` assembly.

Thanks

Comment: Do you know the namespace used in the assembly? An assembly can contain multiple resource packages

Comment: It will certainly be in the .Properties namespace @NineBerry

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
    private ResourceManager GetResourceManager(Assembly assembly)
    {
        // Guess namespace name 
        var namespaceName = Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(assembly.CodeBase);
        namespaceName = namespaceName + ".Properties.Resources";

        return new ResourceManager(namespaceName, assembly);
    }
```